# Sum entire column in excel except for certain rows

Tags: excel

For a spreadsheet of mine, I want the sum of an entire column, no matter how many entries a column is. This was previously solved by

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to do all but the first 2 rows of column A.

```
=SUM(A2:A)
```

does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Missing a key piece of information.  I suspect you want to exclude `A1` because thats the cell your formula is in.

Answer (score 9):

You could use

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUM(A1:A2)
```

or, if you know that the cells you exclude are numeric,

```
=SUM(A:A)-A1-A2
```

Comment: Though if A1 or A2 has non-numeric values this may error out.

Comment: @JBKing I'm pretty sure it treats non-numeric values as 0

Comment: What if I'm trying to avoid circular reference warnings?

Comment: @user1848437 Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

[MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/82890-exclude-cells-formula-using-whole-column.html) has a couple of suggestions:

```
=SUM(A3:A65536)
```

OR

```
=SUM(A3:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,A:A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=Sum($A$3:$A$1048576)
```

Should work